# Why the server is not receiving the answer of the client on socket.io/node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, socket.io

I try to make that when the user is connected to the node.js server, the server asks if he is ready, if yes, the user returns a callback. However, I can not get the callback to the server.

Server-side:

```
io.on('connection', function (client) {
  client.on('ongoing_connect', function (data) {  
  // Working
    client.emit('user_ready', function (response) {
        // Not working
        console.log('Response received');
    });
  });
})
```

Client-side:

```
socket.emit('ongoing_connect');

socket.on('user_ready', function (callback) {
// Working
callback(true);
});
```

I hope someone could tell me where I missed myself, this is my first in the world of node.js

Comment: So what triggers `ongoing_connect`?

Comment: Forgot to add it @James, now it's there

Comment: You can't really pass functions via `emit`.

Comment: In the docs of socket.io, they are doing this: `socket.emit('question', 'do you think so?', function (answer) {});`. So how am I suppose to do it ?

Comment: Acknowledgements for `emit` are only support for client-side IIRC.